# Transferred XLM to my old address? How can I recover?

Tags: xlm

I have transferred my xlm from Binance to BitBns. I sent to the saved address. Later I realised BitBns changed my xlm address. I have given the correct memo which is still active. It's been 24 hours my XLM still not credited to my account. Please advise, how can I recover my XLM?

Answer (score 0):

If the destination address is controlled by BitBns, you may have some hope here. I would email them with an explanation and I bet they would work with you to recover the funds. You would at the very least have to prove ownership of the sending account. This would take some time either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you send any assets to the wrong address generated by Exchanges, then it won't be 100% disaster compared to sending assets to the wrong one not generated by Exchanges. It's because there might be possibilities that the Exchange still has access to your old addresses. So, it'll totally depends on your Exchange.